# vCenter server with both academic and Federal licensing?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-esx, vmware-server, licensing, vmware-vcenter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

### Background

We have two servers running VMWare Academic licensing and just purchased two more under Federal licensing.

The academic licensing will be converted soon and we'll be moving our VMs over to the new systems. However, we'll still need access to the two academic servers to do this.

### Question

- Is vCenter server licensed separately from ESXi hosts or does the licensing apply to specific hosts? If so, this seems like it wouldn't be a problem at all.
- Can I upgrade the licensing on our existing vCenter server from academic to Federal in order to add these two new hosts?
- Can academic and Federal licenses co-exist in this sort of setup?

Thanks!

Comment: Due to the nature of software licensing, it is off-topic for Server Fault. What might be valid for you in your locality might not be valid for me. Companies sometimes have specific policies or EULAs that differ on a customer-to-customer basis. You should call your licensing/sales rep, not ask here.

Comment: Wasn't aware of that but it makes sense. I'll rephrase my question around vCenter's technical capabilities, since that's what I'm concerned with. Thanks!